# separation of string into arrays of x and y

Tags: c++, arrays, string, point

i am trying to receive a string of points like this (2,4),(5,8),(12,7),(15.54,3.65) and separate it into x array and y array please help still a beginner I have tried this and it is disastrous

```
string polygons;
int i = 0;
int length = polygons.length();
string x[10000];
int index = 0;
int k = 0;
getline(cin, polygons);

for (i = 0; i < length; i++) 
{
    if (polygons[i] == '(') 
    {
        k = polygons.substr(i + 1, 20).find_first_of(",");

        x[index] = polygons.substr(i + 1, ((k + i) - (i + 1)));
        index++;
    }
}

int a = 0;  
string y[10000]; 
int index2 = 0;
int c = 0;

for (a = 0; a < length; a++) 
{
    if (polygons.substr(a) == ",") 
    {
        c = polygons.substr(a + 1, 20).find_first_of(")");
    }

    y[index2] = polygons.substr(a + 1, ((c + a) - (a + 1)));
    index2++;
}
```

Comment: Recommend sorting out the brackets and providing a [mcve]

Comment: Recomendation: break the job down. [Use `std::string::find`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/find) to help find  the '(' and ')' and then print out the stuff between them. Once you have that working, replace the print out code with [`std::stringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_stringstream) and `std::getline` to split into the numbers that used to be between the brackets and print the numbers. When that all works correctly and you have a stream of number pairs, find a good way to store the pairs.

Comment: You should use `std::vector` over arrays in C++.

Answer (score 0):

To convert points from being one string to points with numerical values, you can utilize `.find_first_of()` and `std::stod()`. This is my code for converting your points string to numerical values.

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using std::string;
using std::vector;
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

class Point
{
public:
    Point(double x= 0, double y= 0) : m_x(x), m_y(y) {}
    inline double getX() const { return m_x; }
    inline double getY() const { return m_y; }
private:
    double m_x, m_y;
};

vector<Point> strPoints2NumPoints(const string& strPoints)
{
    vector<Point> points;

    for (int i(0); i < strPoints.size(); ++i){

        if ( strPoints[i] == '(' ){
            // extract X & Y values as string
            string temp = strPoints.substr(i+1, strPoints.find_first_of(")",i)-i-1 );
            // convert X as strig to double 
            double X = std::stod(  temp.substr(0,temp.find(',')) );
            // convert Y as string to double
            double Y = std::stod(  temp.substr(temp.find(',')+1) );
            points.push_back(Point(X,Y));
         }
    }

    return points;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    string strPoints("(2,4),(5,8),(12,7),(15.54,3.65)");
    vector<Point> numPoints;

    cout << "Points as string: " << strPoints << endl;

    numPoints = strPoints2NumPoints(strPoints);

    cout << "Points as numbers: " << endl;
    for(int i(0); i < numPoints.size(); ++i ){
        cout << "Point:<" << numPoints[i].getX() << "," << numPoints[i].getY() << ">" << endl;
    }


    return 0;
}
```

The output of the preceding code is

```
Points as string: (2,4),(5,8),(12,7),(15.54,3.65)
Points as numbers:
Point:<2,4>
Point:<5,8>
Point:<12,7>
Point:<15.54,3.65>
```

Comment: @Antonio, if you think this answer solved your problem, pleases accept it by clicking on the check mark. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

According to your codes and logic, I have edited the codes and handled the bugs:

```
string polygons;
int i = 0;
string x[10000];
int index = 0;
int k = 0;
getline(cin, polygons);
int length = polygons.length();

for (i = 0; i < length; i++)
{
    if (polygons[i] == '(')
    {
        // k = polygons.substr(i + 1, 20).find_first_of(",");
        k = polygons.find_first_of(",", i);

        // x[index] = polygons.substr(i + 1, ((k + i) - (i + 1)));
        x[index] = polygons.substr(i + 1, k - i - 1);
        index++;
    }
}

int a = 0;
string y[10000];
int index2 = 0;
int c = 0;

for (a = 0; a < length; a++)
{
    /*
    if (polygons.substr(a) == ",")
    {
        c = polygons.substr(a + 1, 20).find_first_of(")");
    }

    y[index2] = polygons.substr(a + 1, ((c + a) - (a + 1)));
    index2++;
    */
    if (polygons[a] == ',' && polygons[a + 1] != '(')
    {
        k = polygons.find_first_of(")", a);
        y[index2] = polygons.substr(a + 1, k - a - 1);
        index2++;
    }
}
```

Here is my code, just improve and simplify your code style:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    std::string Polygons;
    getline(std::cin, Polygons);

    std::vector<std::string> XCoords;
    for (int i = 0; i < Polygons.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (Polygons[i] == '(')
        {
            auto CommaIndex = Polygons.find_first_of(",", i);

            XCoords.push_back(Polygons.substr(i + 1, CommaIndex - i - 1));
        }
    }

    std::vector<std::string> YCoords;
    for (int i = 0; i < Polygons.length(); ++i)
    {
        if (Polygons[i] == ',' && Polygons[i + 1] != '(')
        {
            auto Index = Polygons.find_first_of(")", i);

            YCoords.push_back(Polygons.substr(i + 1, Index - i - 1));
        }
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Hope it's helpful.

Comment: thank you and thank you for your time  that was exactly what i was looking for t